# Bluetooth in Android: how to access my Bluetooth address?

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is a very simple question: how can I get my Bluetooth address in Android and save it into an string ?

Comment: Can you expand your question a little? Why do you want to get that address? Do you have any experience with Bluetooth on Android or other platforms?

Comment: because i want to convert it to QR code and with another cellphone scan this QR code and connect to bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

```
String MAC_ADDR = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAdress();
```

Don't forget the following: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

Have you search for it before posting?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String address = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```